# Xamarin Android C# filterable / searchview with recyclerview and checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, searchview

I've Created and App with Search View comes up with RecyclerView with Check box. When  i checked a checkbox then search the checked checkbox becomes uncheck. How can i resolve the issue? Checkbox state when searching state the checkbox is still checked. Thanks fellow programmers

Screenshot 1: 
[Application View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcxxG.png)

When checking item in recycler view : 
[Selecting Item Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbsp7.png)

When i searched the item the checkbox state changes it becomes unchecked item:  [Searching the item becomes unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMGFL.png)

```
public class SelectBranch : AppCompatActivity
{
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    List<Info_LoadBranch> loadBranch = new List<Info_LoadBranch>();
    BranchAdapter holder;

    Android.Widget.SearchView searchViewBranch;

    List<string> SelectedBranchCode = new List<string>();

    Button BtnProceed;

    string dbPath;

    SQLiteConnection db;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_select);

        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView1);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        BtnProceed = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnProceed);

        BtnProceed.Click += BtnProceed_Click;

        LoadData();

        searchViewBranch = FindViewById<Android.Widget.SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView1);
        searchViewBranch.QueryTextChange += SearchViewBranch_QueryTextChange;





        GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode = new List<string>();


        // Create your application here
    }

    private void SearchViewBranch_QueryTextChange(object sender, Android.Widget.SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var adapter = new BranchAdapter(this, FindInsideList(e.NewText));
        holder.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<Info_LoadBranch> FindInsideList(string text)
    {
        if (text != null && text.Length > 0)
        {
            List<Info_LoadBranch> filteredList = new List<Info_LoadBranch>();
            foreach (var itm in loadBranch)
            {
                if (itm != null)
                {
                    text = text.ToLower();

                    if (itm.BranchName != null ? itm.BranchName.ToLower().Contains(text) : false)
                    {
                        filteredList.Add(itm);
                    }
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }
        return loadBranch;

    }


    private void BtnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode.Count > 0)
        {

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Inquiry));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();

        }
        else
        {
            DialogHelper.ShowAlertMessage(this, "Exception", "Please select Branch");
            return;
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        dbPath = Path.Combine(BaseVariable.DEFAULT_APP_SETTINGS_DB_PATH, BaseVariable.DEFAULT_SQLITE_DB_COMPANY);
        db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);




        loadBranch = db.Query<Info_LoadBranch>("Select BranchCode, BranchName from BranchDB");


        holder = new BranchAdapter(this, loadBranch);
        //ListViewSelectedBranch.Adapter = output;

        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        holder.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(holder);


    }

    public class BranchAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter 
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        AppCompatActivity activity;
        private List<Info_LoadBranch> branchesList;



        public BranchAdapter(AppCompatActivity activity, List<Info_LoadBranch> branchesList)
        {
            //this.items = items;
            this.activity = activity;
            this.branchesList = branchesList;
            //this.branchesList = branchesList.OrderBy(s => s.BranchName).ToList();


         }


        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return branchesList.Count;
            }
        }

        public Filter Filter { get; private set; }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.adapter_selectbranch, parent, false);
            //itemView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.listItem1);

            PickingViewHolder vh = new PickingViewHolder(itemView);

            return vh;
        }


          private Dictionary<int, bool> map = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            var item = branchesList[position];
            PickingViewHolder vh = holder as PickingViewHolder;

            vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyListener(map, position));
            vh.LblBranch.Text = item.BranchName;
            vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Tag = item.BranchCode;



            if (map != null && map.ContainsKey(position))
            {

                vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked = true;

                // vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked = branchesList[position].IsChecked;
            }
            else
            {
                vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked = false;

            }




            //vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked = branchesList[position].IsChecked;
            //vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckedChangeListener(this.activity));

            //if (map != null && map.ContainsKey(position))
            //{
            //    vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked = true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    vh.BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked = false;
            //}
            //if (position != 0)
            //{
            //    var linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent,
            //                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            //    linearLayoutParams.SetMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
            //    vh.MainLinearLayout.LayoutParameters = linearLayoutParams;
            //}


            //vh.Image.SetImageResource (mPhotoAlbum[position].PhotoID);


        }

        class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
        {
            public Dictionary<int, bool> map;
            public int mPosotion;
            string name;

            public MyListener(Dictionary<int, bool> map, int position)
            {
                this.map = map;
                mPosotion = position;
            }

            public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
            {
                if (isChecked == true)
                {
                    if (!map.ContainsKey(mPosotion))
                    {
                        map.Add(mPosotion, true);
                        name = (string)buttonView.Tag;


                    GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode.Add(name);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    map.Remove(mPosotion);
                    foreach (var a in GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode)
                    {
                        GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode.Remove(name);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class PickingViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public LinearLayout MainLinearLayout { get; set; }

            public TextView LblBranch { get; set; }
            public CheckBox BranchCodeCheckBox { get; set; }
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

            public PickingViewHolder(View itemView):base(itemView)
            {
                //Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView);
                MainLinearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
                LblBranch = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewBranch);
                BranchCodeCheckBox = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBoxSelect);

                // Detect user clicks on the item view and report which item
                // was clicked (by layout position) to the listener:
               // itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);

                BranchCodeCheckBox.Click += delegate
                {
                    if (BranchCodeCheckBox.Checked)
                    {


                        IsChecked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        IsChecked = false;
                    }
                };

            }


        }
        void OnClick(int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
                ItemClick(this, position);
        }


    }


    public class CheckedChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
    {
        public Activity activity;
        string name;
        public CheckedChangeListener(Activity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                name = (string)buttonView.Tag;
                GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode.Add(name);


            }
            else if (!isChecked)
            {

                foreach (var a in GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode)
                {
                    GlobalVariable.SelectedBranchCode.Remove(name);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Because there is no corresponding update to this value : `private Dictionary<int, bool> map = new Dictionary<int, bool>();`

Comment: I think i added through the MyListener class :                         
                       map.Add(mPosotion, true);
                        name = (string)buttonView.Tag;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use a separate dataset(`Dictionary<int, bool> map`) to store the position, you need to deal with the Item data and position separately.

```
private Dictionary<int, bool> map = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
```

Try another method, just add a field in your Object model : `Info_LoadBranch`. For example:

```
 public bool isChecked {  get; set; }
```

And initialize the variable to `false`.

And When you check (or uncheck) the checkBox, you can refer to the following code:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
        //***********************
        Photo item =   mPhotoAlbum[position];

        //***********************
        //vh.MyCheckBox.Tag = position;

        vh.Caption.Text = item.Caption;

        vh.MyCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        vh.MyCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyListener(item));
        vh.MyCheckBox.Checked = item.isChecked;

    }
```

And `MyListener`

```
class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
    {
        Photo photo;

        public MyListener( Photo item)
        {
            this.photo = item;
        }

        public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
        {
            photo.isChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }
```

If you want to find the checked Items, you can filter like this:

```
            List<Photo> checkedList = new List<Photo>();

            for (int i=0;i< loadBranch.Count;i++) {
                Photo temp = loadBranch[i];                 

                if (temp.isChecked) {
                    checkedList.Add(temp);
                }
            }
```

Note: the model `Photo` is my model, you just use yours.